# How to send string id to controller using actionlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am tring to have links link this
/View/test
it is working only if it is int like /View/1

my view action link

```
   @Html.ActionLink(item.className, "Viewe", "subject", new {id =item.className  },null)
```

my control action

```
       public ViewResult Viewe(string id)
    {
        //some database
        return View();
    }
```

i get this error `Server Error in '/' Application.`
if i change the id into anything it works fine but the link will looks like 
this : View?anything=par

image of the error

[image: image of the error]

route code

```
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
           routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Check your **Route.Config** file under **App_Start**. you will find a code snippet that handles the route. By default it accepts `controller/action/id`. In order to accept "anything" as param and form a user-friendly URL, you need to create a custom route and replace "id" param with "anything".

Comment: i still have the same problem i doesn't care if i use param as "id" or "anything" , id is fine for me but i still have the same error

Comment: Don't use action name `View`, you are hiding parameterless version of `View` controller method which will try to find a `.cshtml` file with action corresponding name. You may better do the following way: `[ActionName("View")]
        public ViewResult ViewAction(string id)`

Comment: Please take a snap shot of error description and share it on above post. That will be more helpful.

Comment: i have updated the question with the error image and also i have changed View and still no luck

Comment: Could you please also provide your `RouteConfig` code?

Comment: it is the Default i didn't change and thing in it

Comment: Do you have a method name `Viewe` in `SubjetController` - the method your have shown is `View` (not `Viewe`). And the `ActionLink()` code you have shown will not generate that based on the routes you have shown

Comment: On the print screen your action name is `Viewe`, please update the code of controller action appropriately.

Comment: sorry for that i was test what @IvanGritsenko told me to change the action name

Comment: The amended code you have shown works fine based on the routes you have shown. What is the actual html rendered by you `ActionLink()` method.

Comment: Is it possible that you have `return HttpNotFound();` somewhere in you action method?

Comment: here is the first link <a href="/subject/Viewe/first_primary%20">first_primary </a>

Comment: it is solved now thanks the problem that there was extra space in the database name that make the problem

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.ClassName, "Viewe", "Subject", new { Id = item.ClassName }, null)
```